# How do I create a function in C that generates a random number that doesn't repeat

Tags: c

How do I create a function in C that generates random numbers but also does not use the same number twice? I've tried to use `int usedNumbers[numPeople]` variable, but the compiler gives me an error C2057. Is there an other way to do this? I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator It will generate unique random non-repeating numbers and be guaranteed to cycle through all numbers for the period (e.g. 2^31) before repeating the sequence.

Comment: A "random number that doesn't repeat" isn't truly random.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sometimes it is needed. Like randomly assigned aeroplane seeat

Comment: @0___________ That's not a random number.  That's a random shuffle of a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same basic strategy would work in pretty much any programming language. It works basically like a deck of cards.

- Fill an array with values.
- Shuffle those values.
- Pick from the array in order.

You'll get random numbers, and they won't repeat.

The exact details of how to do these three steps are left as an exercise for the OP.

If you try to keep track of already chosen numbers, and then pick until you don't get one of those, you run into the problem that you don't really know how long it'll take to find a unique random number.

Answer (score 0):

> `int usedNumbers[numPeople]` variable, but the compiler gives me an
> error C2057

MS compilers do not support VLAs. You need to dynamically allocate the space.

```
int *usedNumbers = malloc(numPeople * sizeof(*usedNumbers));
```

After use (when not needed) `free` it